# Cannot invoke toCompletableFuture() because the return value of apply(Object) is null while working with method that returns CompletionStage<Void>

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, completable-future

I'm stuck on an error:

> java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage.toCompletableFuture()" because the return value of "java.util.function.Function.apply(Object)" is null

The line the error's pointing to is indicated below:

```
.handle(
    (result, ex) -> {
      if (ex == null) {
        return null;
      } else if (ex.getCause() instanceof NotFoundException) {
        return configStore.doSomething(); /** returns a CompletionStage<Void> **/
      }
      throw new CompletionException(ex.getCause());
    })
.thenCompose(x -> x); /** error points here **/
```

I think the `.thenCompose(x -> x);` is necessary because `.handle(...)` does not unwrap a `CompletionStage<...>`, resulting in a `CompletionStage<CompletionStage<...>>` when chaining inside the `.handle(...)`.

To address the error I also tried returning this instead of `null`...

```
.handle(
    (result, ex) -> {
      if (ex == null) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null); /** tried this **/
      } else if ...
```

...but then I get this error (screenshot for more context):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out while writing the question; self-answering because my Google and SO searches with the error message weren't pointing me to this solution.

The solution was actually suggested by IntelliJ (blue text in the screenshot) but I didn't see it. Because `null` is ambiguous in type, you have to cast the expression like so:

```
.handle(
    (result, ex) -> {
      if (ex == null) {
        return CompletableFuture.<Void>completedFuture(null); /** cast to <Void> **/
      } else if ...
```

Comment: That works for `completedFuture(null)` but what about your original `configStore.doSomething()`?

Comment: I believe doSomething()'s signature of CompletionStage<Void> (or CompletionStage<Empty> from protobuf—either worked) gave the "hint" that was required.

Comment: Then, `.handle( (result, ex) -> ex == null? CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null): ex.getCause() instanceof NotFoundException? configStore.doSomething(): CompletableFuture.failedFuture(ex.getCause()) ) .thenCompose(x -> x);` should also work.

Comment: Ohhh so using failedFuture() instead of throw CompletionException() would give the type hint it needs. The semantics of failedFuture() seems superior to me as well. Thanks!

Comment: Using `failedFuture()` allows to use the ternary operator (`condition? value1: value2`) which has better type inference than `if(condition) return value1; else return value2;` here.